# Boolean as methods parameter is not changing state

Tags: c#, methods, boolean

I want to change the state of a boolean in a function. My function has 4 parameters and the fourth one is a bool which is by default true, but I want to change it's state to false inside the function .

I am calling my methode is following,

```
SlotCheck("Red", "red_small_c", puzzle_9, GameControl.control.scoreRedGems, GameControl.control.stone_9);
```

**GameControl.control.stone_9** is by default true. It should become false once visibilty is set to false ..but that is not happing... stone_9 stays true.

```
public void SlotCheck(string gemColor,string slotColor,GameObject puzzleStuk,int scoreGem,bool Visibility)
{
    if (DragHandler2.itemBegingDragged.name.Contains(gemColor) && DragHandler2.itemBegingDragged.transform.parent.name == slotColor)
    {
        Debug.Log(DragHandler2.itemBegingDragged.name);
        Visibility=false;
        puzzleStuk.SetActive(visibility);
        Debug.Log(GameControl.control.stone_9);    //true
        DragHandler2.itemBegingDragged.SetActive(false);

    }
```

I expect GameControl.control.stone_9  to change it's state to false because I am changing the state of the parameter (Visibility) to false but  GameControl.control.stone_9  stays true.

Comment: Pass the boolean using `ref`, The reason you need to do this is so c# has referenced access, and can modify the actual boolean, not a cloned parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are under the impression that changing the value of an argument will be reflected to the caller (your first code block).  This is not the case unless you use `ref` or `out` for the parameter/argument.  This will work so long as `GameControl.control.stone_9` is a field and not a property.

In short, arguments are passed by value unless using those keywords.  (for reference types this is true as well, but it's a bit more complicated as what's copied is the reference, not the actual object itself)

Other answers have explained the syntax (needing to use `ref` both for the argument and the parameter.)

Also, one bit of advice, never capitalize your variables or parameters as when you do most C# readers will see them as properties in the containing class, causing confusion.

Comment: Thank you very much sir I actually really didn't know about the ref  and out. Appreciated

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the value of a variable inside a Method, you should define it by ref:

```
public void SlotCheck(string gemColor,string slotColor,GameObject puzzleStuk,int scoreGem,ref bool Visibility)
{
   //method stuff
     Visibility = false;
}
```

and then call your method like:

```
SlotCheck("Red", "red_small_c", puzzle_9, GameControl.control.scoreRedGems, ref GameControl.control.stone_9);
```

Comment: well I just said what you are saying, the variable name does not matter, name the parameter whatever you like

Answer (score 0):

1- In `SlotCheck` the four parameter should be `ref bool Visibility`

Or

Inside the `if` statement you should do this

```
GameControl.control.stone_9 = false;
```